# passing derived data type assumed shape arrays from a subroutine to a function in fortran 90

Tags: arrays, fortran, derived-types

I quite new to fortran .And i am using a lib built in fortran , the lib has many TYPE arrays.
I try to assign the values to the TYPE arrays in the lib  through a c program using the following method.
 I have built a c-fortran interface where i get values from  a sqlite database into a c structure array in c prg.Then pass this structure array it to a fortran subroutine  where i declare  it as a derived type, matching the definition of TYPE variable declared in the lib .Then i copy the values from the passed arrays  to actual TYPE arrays declared in the lib and pass it to fortran function .

What is happening is the values in the arrays are passed ok from c to fortran subroutine , i print them to check them in fortran subroutine, but the values are getting garbled when the arrays are passed from the subroutine to the function . I am passing the arrays as assumed shaped array. The function is declared inside a module hence i thought the calling subroutine will not require an interface .

I am not exactly understanding what is happening , i have also tried using the sequence in the TYPE declaration .
I am using g95 , gcc 4.0.3 complilers.
All the values in the arrays are of type REAL(KIND =8) , and the equivalent in the c program is double .

Consider a lib which has TYPE(something), TYPE(Something2)  declared in it. I import the lib as a module in a fortran subroutine .

Lets assume

```
           TYPE(something_lib) is

              REAL(kind =8) ::A 
              REAL(kind=8)  ::B

            END TYPE
```

in the lib

```
 TYPE(SOMETHING2_lib) !this is also declare in the lib


           !I have a C program  in which

            ! in which
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
     // C program

  struct SomethingC    

   {
    double a


     double b

 } ;

  struct SomethingC  x[2]

  struct  something2C s[2]  // something similar to the first struct


//i fill the values in x ,s from database in proper format.(doubles).

 //i call the fortran subroutine in the c program

   A_(x,s);   //call to fortran subroutine
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     // the fortan subroutine

```
     SUBROUTINE A (x,s)

        USE Lib_module       ! this LIB_Module also contains the function func


         TYPE G

            REAL(kind =8)        ! this is defined similar to TYPE something(in lib) by me
             REAL(kind =8)

         END TYPE G


          TYPE G2

            similar to TYPE Something2 in lib

          END TYPE G2


         TYPE(something_lib) :: D(2)      !derived type declared in lib
         TYPE(Something2_lib)::E(2)       ! derived type declared in lib
         TYPE(G)::x(2)            
         TYPE(G2)::s(2)           


  ! x, s are struct arrays from c which are now declared in the fortran function


          copy code for 
          copying values from
            x to D
            s to E

          print all values of 
             D

          Print all values of 
            E


         !this prints the values correct as expected for both x,d


          func(D,E)    ! this function is defined in the lib . The function is in the                      

                     !  LIB_module                    
                     ! so no interface will be required (i think)


         ! IN the  Function


           FUNCTION func(D,E) (while debugging)


            TYPE(something_lib) :: INTENT (IN) D(:)
            TYPE (something2_lib)::INTENT (IN) E(:)


              when i try to print values of D , E in the 
              function i get garbled values like 

                1180333333

               2.33419537006E-313

        !when  out of the function  and back in the subroutine i.e after the call(while                        debugging)
                ! if I print the values of D,E here  they print ok

  END SUBROUTINE
```

Thus they are getting garbled after they are passed in the function , but are ok in the 
subroutine .
My question is why is this happening ?
how can i solve it?

Comment: We are not exactly understanding what you are doing.  It is very difficult to see the problems in your code.

Comment: A productive way to proceed at this point is to give us either the code, a truncated version of the code with the relevant parts, or a skeletal/schematic version of the code. And, of course, any errors that are being generated upon execution.

Comment: @High Performance  I will edit my question to provide a skeleton .

Comment: @codefor: yukkkk, please format you code properly.

Comment: Unless I have missed something it, it is not clear where you call the function.   Do you "use" the module that defines the function from that caller?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark sorry abt that .

Comment: @M.S.B. the function is called in the subroutine , the subroutine has the statement Use Lib_Module , in the module the function is defined .Thanks for the reply MSB

Comment: @codefor: yukkkk, please format your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the ISO C Binding, which makes passing variables between C & Fortran part of the Fortran language standard.   This will require gcc/gfortran 4.3 or higher; I'm not sure about g95 versions. However, assumed-shaped arrays as arguments to C are not supported.   Assumed-shaped arrays are high-level, containing not just the array but info about the size, and passing them to C would probably require understanding the internals of a particular Fortran compiler.

Comment: hI Thanks you for your reply.But I am not trying to pass assumed shape array to C . I am trying to pass it from a fortran subroutine to a fortran function , the function is in the  contains of a module.